# selenium webdriver - construct action click and sendkeys

Tags: java, selenium, constructor

I have bunch of following pieces:

```
WebElement L3_Y1_total_x = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'sumCell blahblah total')]"));

String L3_Y1_total_x1_value = L3_Y1_total_x.getAttribute("value");
WebElement L3_C1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'cell blahblah1 decimal')]"));
L3_C1.click();L3_C1.sendKeys("3,00");L3_C1.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
try {wait10s.until(Attribute_Not_To_Be.attributeNotToBe(L3_Y1_total_x, "value", L3_Y1_total_x1_value));} catch (TimeoutException e) {};

String L3_Y2_total_x1_value = L3_Y2_total_x.getAttribute("value");
WebElement L3_C2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'cell cell blahblah2 decimal')]"));
L3_C2.click();L3_C2.sendKeys("3,00");L3_C2.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
try {wait10s.until(Attribute_Not_To_Be.attributeNotToBe(L3_Y2_total_x, "value", L3_Y2_total_x1_value));} catch (TimeoutException e) {};

String L3_Y3_total_x1_value = L3_Y3_total_x.getAttribute("value");
WebElement L3_C3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'cell blahblah3 decimal')]"));
L3_C3.click();L3_C3.sendKeys("3,00");L3_C3.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
try {wait10s.until(Attribute_Not_To_Be.attributeNotToBe(L3_Y3_total_x, "value", L3_Y3_total_x1_value));} catch (TimeoutException e) {};
```

How can I shrink the code? At least the `element.click();element.sendKeys("xy");...`sequence.

thanks

Comment: Code reviews belong here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Where do `L3_Y2_total_x` and `L3_Y3_total_x` come from?

Comment: similar as L3_Y1_total_x.  WebElement L3_Y2_total_x = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'sumCell other_blahblah total')]"));
WebElement L3_Y3_total_x = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'sumCell other2_blahblah total')]"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should fit your purposes (though I can't try it out right now). Call the function with `L3_Y1_total_x`, `L3_Y2_total_x` and  `L3_Y3_total_x` and the respective Parameter `blahblah`.

```
public void doAction(WebElement elem, String blahblah) {
    String value = elem.getAttribute("value");
    WebElement L3_C1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'cell " + blablah + "decimal')]"));
    L3_C1.click();
    L3_C1.sendKeys("3,00");
    L3_C1.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
    try {
        wait10s.until(Attribute_Not_To_Be.attributeNotToBe(elem, "value", value));
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {};
}
```

Please mind that using underscores as well as capitalized variables violates the widely accepted Java coding conventions. Use camel casing and lowercase variables.